# Ограничение потребляемой процессом памяти

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Могу ли я как-нибудь ограничить объем потребляемой оперативной памяти при запуске приложения ?

Comment: man bash | grep -A32 ulimit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю насколько это подойдет в Вашем случае.
Создаем пользователя, ограничиваем его память. И запускать процесс от его имени.

```
Использование ulimit с пользователем VPUPKIN

Дбавим в конец /etc/profile:

if [ "$USER" = "VPUPKIN" ]; then

ulimit -c 0 # Запрещаем создавать core файлы
ulimit -d 48000 # Ограничиваем максимальный размер сегмента данных в 48 MB
ulimit -s 8192  # Ограничиваем максимальный размер стэка в 8 MB
ulimit -m 48000 # Ограничиваем максимальный размер резидентной части процесса (находящейся в ОЗУ) в  48 MB
ulimit -u 1    # Ограничиваем максимальное число запущенных этим пользователем процессов.
ulimit -n 128   # Ограничиваем максимальное число открытых файлов.
ulimit -f 100000 # Ограничиваем максимальный размер создаваемого файла в 100 MB
ulimit -v 100000 # Ограничиваем максимальный размер используемой виртуальной памяти в 100 MB
fi
```

Для просмотра текущих установок нужно набрать ulimit -a